# Anaconda Prompt unable to correctly use PATH variable

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, anaconda

A few issues going on here.

**Issue # 1 -**
Upon opening Anaconda prompt, I get the following error:

```
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**Issue #2 -** Anaconda is unable to pip install libraries that require Visual C++

When I try to `pip install scikit-surprise`, it returns the following error:

`'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory`

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed, and `cl.exe` exists in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin`.

**Methods I have already tried:**

- Adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin` to my PATH variables
- Using `pip install` in *Visual C++ 2015 x64 x86 cross Build Tools Command Prompt*, as opposed to the Anaconda Prompt
- Installing Visual Studio 2017, including the C++ addon

Comment: How are you opening the anaconda prompt?

Comment: Start Menu > All Programs > Anaconda3 (64 bit) > Anaconda Prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question myself in the hopes this will help others that have this problem in the future.

My path variable did not have system32 correctly defined. I edited my path variable to include the following:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;
```

After that, I restarted the prompt and was able to install the package successfully.